# usar el google maps api en java swing?

Tags: java, api, java-swing, google-maps

Estoy desarrollando una app en java que busca verificar si una dirección es real, como por ejemplo: calle 123 #123 etc etc.

Para esto he encontrado el termino *geocodificar* que implica dar una coordenada a una búsqueda en un mapa.

Mi pregunta es: ¿Cómo puedo usar la API de *google maps* para que mi formulario creado con java swing verifique si existen unas coordenadas asociadas a la dirección que ingreso el usuario?

Comment: Haz *HTTP Request* al webservice de Google: [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start?hl=es)

Answer (score 0):

Cuando se utilizan API's de cualquier tipo que esten publicadas en Internet se maneja el termino de WebService utilizando protocolo [SOA](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arquitectura_orientada_a_servicios) (Arquitectura Orientada a Servicios), en los servicios web se cuenta con 2 tipos de servicios los cuales son:

- REST
- SOAP

El api que publica de Google Maps, es un api que trabaja bajo la tecnologia Rest el cual para el intercambio de información maneja archivos JSON.

Ahora para poder utilizar dicho API, debes saber consumir webservice Rest desde java, en el siguiente enlace le muestra como se consume un webservice Rest con java [AQUI](https://devs4j.com/2017/12/18/aprende-a-consumir-servicios-rest-via-https-leyendo-precios-de-criptomonedas/).

Por otro lado los webservice Rest manejan métodos Http los cuales son:

- POST
- GET
- PUT
- DELETE
- UPDATE
- OPTIONS
- PATH

Según el servicio expuesto se debe utilizar un método en especifico, para el api que necesita utilizaría GET